# How microscopy could be considered as convolution?

Tags: experimental-physics, microscopy

I just read [here](http://www.microscopist.co.uk/essential-techniques/deconvolution/) that "The process of how a lens, or objective, forms an image of any object is called convolution."

When we are talking about convolution, I expect something like this:

$$(f*g) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(\tau)g(t-\tau)\tau'$$

In AFM it all makes sense to me that what we have is a convolution; there is something like convolution kernel running over the sample, etc. But in some sort of microscopy that involves lenses the math of convolution is not clear to me.

Comment: Short answer:  a lens is modelled as a Fourier Transform, changing phase (of wavefront) into intensity (image).